# HTTP to HTTPS with mod_rewrite; Apache needs restart

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, httpd

I just registered and this is my first question.  Let me know if I need to ask this somewhere else.

We have a need to configure a site for SSL and to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.  We decided to use mod_rewrite since we were already making use of some rewrite rules.  The changes were tested in our development environment and it worked as expected.  We made the change to production and found that it works for a few hours but eventually starts failing and the site becomes unavailable.  Once the Apache service is restarted the site comes back up.  Unfortunately it doesn't last and needs to be repeated eventually.

Someone referred me to some guidance that says mod_rewrite isn't recommended and to use VirtualHosts instead.  I'd like to understand why this is the preferred method, and hopefully find a root cause for the issues we're experiencing.  We just turned the rewrite rule off and the site has been stable while listening on both 443 and 80.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS
"Note: Using mod_rewrite to do this isn't the recommended behavior"

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL
"While the  solution is recommended because it is simpler and safer, you can also use mod_rewrite to get the same effect as described here"

Does anyone know specifics over why this is recommended over mod_rewrite? Similar experience?  Recommendation on next steps?

Apache 2.4.18

Running on Windows Server 2008 R2

We've tried `MaxConnectionsPerChild 0` and other values with no difference.  I've seen `MaxConnectionResetsPerChild` reached during the "outage", and those resets don't appear to resolve the issue.. as opposed to manual restart of the Apache service/parent process.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https//wontletmepostlink.duetorep/1$ [R,L]
```

Comment: _mod_rewrite isn't recommended and to use VirtualHosts instead_ -- This is not correct, as `mod_rewrite` and Apache VirtualHosts are not mutually exclusive, and can be used together. VirtualHosts are the preferred way to serve a SSL site, and are the Apache default. However, you would still need a second mechanism to perform the redirect, and this would generally be either `mod_alias` or `mod_rewrite`, as @M Glatki indicates below.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer one of your questions:

`mod_alias`, which provides `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`. `Redirect` is enough for simple redirects, while `RedirectMatch` provides the means for redirecting classes of URLs.

As an additional reference, see [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html), which provides many examples, and a good explanation on why not to use `mod_rewrite` for everything.

> `mod_rewrite` should be considered a last resort, when other alternatives are found wanting. Using it when there are simpler alternatives leads to configurations which are confusing, fragile, and hard to maintain.